# React application developed using node JS v10

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a main react application in which many other react applications have been developed. This was developed way before I joined. However, this is bothering me , because react applications keep coming in, and technically we keep building using nodejs10 to each new application.
Iam overthinking ?, or something can happen in the future
Can this be supported by node js?
I also considered updating all applications to the latest nodejs. But I'm fearful of the damages or if this idea is even feasible to implement?

Answer (score 1):

From my personal experience, it's quite rare for a Node upgrade to break a React build.
But it all depends on the complexity of the app and the packages used and how old are the dependencies.

I wouldn't say you're overthinking, Node 10 support ended at the end of April so it would be advisable to upgrade to a more recent version.

I would ask the relevant person to have a couple of days to tackle the tech debt and try to upgrade Node to 16.

If you are using `nvm` you could switch to Node 16 using the `--reinstall-packages-from` command targeting your current version and try to build.
It's going to take you a couple of minutes.

You can always switch back to 10 with a single command.

Comment: Thank you , so this application is hosting 20 more applications , and each has been configure using node 10 , do we need to also update each and the main one ?